# How to efficiently split month data for summarizing by month

Tags: r, date

When i want to summarize for duration by each month, it may not be reflected, because of long period. How to split data seem like this example?

Example data :

```
data <- data.frame(start_date = c("2020-01-02", "2020-08-21","2020-09-01"), end_date = c("2020-03-01", "2020-09-07", "2020-09-30"), ID = c("A", "B", "C"))
> data
start_date  end_date   ID
2020-01-02  2020-03-01 A
2020-08-21  2020-09-07 B
2020-09-01  2020-09-30 C
```

What i want

```
start_date  end_date   ID
2020-01-02  2020-01-31 A
2020-02-01  2020-02-28 A
2020-03-01- 2020-03-01 A
2020-08-21  2020-08-31 B
2020-09-01  2020-09-07 B
2020-09-01  2020-09-30 C
```

Answer (score 2):

It's little bit messy but it may helps.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data <- data.frame(start_date = c("2020-01-02", "2020-08-21","2020-09-01"), end_date = c("2020-03-01", "2020-09-07", "2020-09-30"), ID = c("A", "B", "C"))
data %>%
  mutate(start_date = as.Date(start_date),
         end_date = as.Date(end_date)) %>%
  mutate(s_m = as.Date(as.yearmon(format(start_date, "%Y-%m"))), 
         e_m = as.Date(as.yearmon(format(end_date, "%Y-%m")))) %>%
  mutate(s_m = if_else(s_m < start_date, s_m + months(1), s_m), 
         ) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(start_date =   c(start_date,seq.Date(s_m, e_m, by = "month")),
           end_date = c(seq.Date(s_m, e_m, by = "month")-1, end_date)) %>%
  filter(month(start_date) == month(end_date)) %>%
  select(-s_m, -e_m)

  ID    start_date end_date  
  <chr> <date>     <date>    
1 A     2020-01-02 2020-01-31
2 A     2020-02-01 2020-02-29
3 A     2020-03-01 2020-03-01
4 B     2020-08-21 2020-08-31
5 B     2020-09-01 2020-09-07
6 C     2020-09-01 2020-09-30
```

Comment: Suggest this simplification. which shortens the code and eliminates dependence on lubridate.  `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(zoo); data %>% mutate(start_date = as.Date(start_date), end_date = as.Date(end_date)) %>%  group_by(ID) %>% 
  group_modify(~ { s <- seq(as.yearmon(min(.$start_date)), as.yearmon(max(.$end_date)), 1/12); complete(., start_date = pmax(start_date, as.Date(s))) %>%  mutate(end_date = pmin(na.locf0(end_date), as.Date(as.yearmon(start_date), frac = 1))) }) %>%  ungroup`